# Android: How do I display only the data of the user who is currently logged in?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I did the registration through Firebase. The data is stored like this:

[image]

Each user can fill out a form and the data from it is displayed on a separate screen in RecyclerView. The problem is that now the users are not separated in any way. This is what user records look like:

[image]

How can I make only those entries created by a particular user be displayed? I need to check exactly by user id.
Now I output the data this way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ...

   dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User Data");
        dRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        userData = new ArrayList<UserData>();
}

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserData uData = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserData.class);
                userData.add(uData);
            }
            userAdapter = new UserAdapter(MainActivity.this, userData);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
};
```

How can I do that? The IDs are different everywhere.

UPD:

Create user:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            User user = new User(fullName, age, email, phone);
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

User:

```
public class User {
    public String fullName, age, email, phone;
    public User() {

    }

    public User(String fullName, String age, String email, String phone) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

UserData:

```
public class UserData {

    String id, userName, userLastName, userOtchestvo, userAppeal, userOrganisation, userPhone, userEmail, userVK, userFB;

    public UserData(String id, String userName, String userLastName, String userOtchestvo, String userAppeal, String userOrganisation, String userPhone, String userEmail, String userVK, String userFB) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userLastName = userLastName;
        this.userOtchestvo = userOtchestvo;
        this.userAppeal = userAppeal;
        this.userOrganisation = userOrganisation;
        this.userPhone = userPhone;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userVK = userVK;
        this.userFB = userFB;
    }

    public UserData() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    ...
```

I add data to Firebase at the click of a button:

```
add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String userId, userName, userLastName, userOtchestvo, userAppeal, userOrganisation, userPhone, userEmail, userVK, userFB;
                userId = database.push().getKey();
                userName = title_input.getText().toString();
                userLastName = author_input.getText().toString();
                userOtchestvo = pages_input.getText().toString();
                userAppeal = appeal_input.getText().toString();
                userOrganisation = organisation_input.getText().toString();
                userPhone = phone_input.getText().toString();
                userEmail = email_input.getText().toString();
                userVK = vk_input.getText().toString();
                userFB = fb_input.getText().toString();

                UserData userData = new UserData(userId, userName, userLastName, userOtchestvo, userAppeal, userOrganisation, userPhone, userEmail, userVK, userFB);
                database.child(userId).setValue(userData);
            }
        });
```

Comment: when you are inserting data to user data just use the user id as key. Then you can easily access the current logged in user's data.

Comment: can you please show me an example? I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: upload the code where you insert user data.

Comment: Added. If I understood correctly what I needed to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
database.push().getKey()
```

This doesn't give you the userid, this only gives you a random unique key which is not equals to userid.

So do this instead.

```
userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

This will give you the `userId` of the current logged in user.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226759/discussion-on-answer-by-suvajit-patra-android-how-do-i-display-only-the-data-of).